# My URL breaks because of jsessionid

Tags: coldfusion

I have a serious problem with jsessionid that is automatically pasted into my url. This extra value looks like this:

```
 ;jsessionid=5046392DAA8687BE348FB51B57B69DB3.cfusion
```

This is pasted into my url causing Page Not found error because it is pasted in the middle of url like this:

```
 https://mycompany.com;jsessionid=5046392DAA8687BE348FB51B57B69DB3.cfusion/index.cfm?p=home&home=current
```

But this is only happening when I open the link in IE (mine is IE 11).
When I open it in FireFox or Chrome I don't get this problem. It normally shows up as:

```
 https://mycompany.com/index.cfm?p=home&home=current
```

My link looks like this:

```
 <a id="#url.home#" href="index.cfm?p=home&home=current" target="iframe_main">HOME</a>
```

But at home.cfm On top of the page I have:

```
   <CFIF IsDefined("session.usergroup") AND session.usergroup EQ 0>
        <CFLOCATION url="/index.cfm?p=home&form=current&loginerr=Your session is expired. Please re-login again">
   <CFELSE>
      show the page
   </CFIF>
```

I tried using AddToken = "NO" attribute in the CFLOCATION. This will eliminate my problem in IE BUT I get a new problem. My session does not work!!
My Dep is switching to ColdFusion2016 and I'm working on this in CF2016.
Is there a way to fix this issue? please help, thank you!

Comment: This looks like the session ID is not stored in the cookie. IE has it if the Domain contains an underscore or if you use J2EE sessions and have no dot `.` in the domain.

Comment: Is enabling the cookie in application.cfc enough? I did <cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = "YES" /> and it seems OK but not sure if this is the answer